# Bash output appears without line breaks when posted to teams channel using webhook

Tags: bash, microsoft-teams

I am storing the output `df -h` in a variable and then posting it to a ms teams channel using curl. However on the teams channel it appears without any line breaks. How would we send something with the line breaks as it appears on the shell when I enter `df -h` command? I have tried preserving the output by enclosing the command in quotes but whenever I post it the channel displays it as one whole line.

**my_bash_script**

```bash
DF_OUTPUT="$(df -h)"

# Convert formating.
MESSAGE=$( echo "${DF_OUTPUT}" | sed 's/"/\"/g' | sed "s/'/\'/g" )

JSON="{\"title\": \"${TITLE}\", \"text\": \"${MESSAGE}\", \"summary\": \"test\",  \"markdown\": \"true\" }"

# Post to Microsoft Teams.
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "${JSON}" "${WEBHOOK_URL}"
```

**teams_channel_output**

[How the output appears on the teams channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWbfJ.png)

**original_bash_script_from**

[The original bash script, i wrote mine using this](https://gist.github.com/chusiang/895f6406fbf9285c58ad0a3ace13d025)

Comment: I presume `df -h` would use unix line endings (`\r`) maybe change them to `\n` instead with something like sed?

Comment: @vaughngx4 Windows uses `\r\n` while UNIX uses just `\n`; that could be the problem but there's also the `"markdown": "true"` in the request, OP might need to format the output with markdown

Comment: @markp-fuso ITYM `sed 's/$/\r/'` instead of `sed 's/\n/\r\n/g'` (unless you add `-z` with GNU sed to read multi-line records).

Comment: What happens if you change your `Content-Type` to `text/plain` ?

Comment: Please go through this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#format-cards-with-markdown to understand the Markdown formatting support in Teams.